# Increasing Cell Height with multiline,without Scrollbar in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Hai 
I am developing a standalone application using Java in which I am using a JTable.The problem is when I enter a multiline text,the entire text is not displayed in the cell while I am typing.I get a scroll when I type a multiline text.How can I get my whole text to be visible while I type.i.e **How can I increase my Cell width in JTable while I am Typing**. But the entire text will displayed only when I click out of that Cell.Can someone help me how to solve this problem

Thank You Chaithu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try a custom [TableCellRenderer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) with JTextArea for example. For typing you'll probably need similar [TableCellEditor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html).

An example can be seen at [Java Specialists' Newsletter : Multi-line cells in JTable in JDK 1.4+](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue106.html).

Comment: Hai 
Thanks for ur answer I have used the code suggested by you.I am sending my code.Its working but he whole text is not displayed while typing in the cell.find my code give me the suggestion where to change the code so that whole text displays in the cell with out scroll after the first line

Comment: find my code in this link
http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10822453#10822453

Comment: @chaithu Did you het it to dysplay the whole text while typing?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! SO is full of buggy examples to calculate row height for multiline cells; this is the one that finally works. Even when the cells are not editable.